# Error when trying to extract zipfile using python (NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported)

Tags: python-3.x, python-zipfile

I am trying to unzip several zip files using a python script. However, an error always occurs at this line of code:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(FILE_PATH) as zfile:
    zfile.extractall(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)
```

The error raised is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ead33468a516> in <module>
      1 with zipfile.ZipFile(FILE_PATH) as zip_ref:
----> 2     zip_ref.extractall(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)

~\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in extractall(self, path, members, pwd)
   1645 
   1646         for zipinfo in members:
-> 1647             self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)
   1648 
   1649     @classmethod

~\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in _extract_member(self, member, targetpath, pwd)
   1698             return targetpath
   1699 
-> 1700         with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
   1701              open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
   1702             shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)

~\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in open(self, name, mode, pwd, force_zip64)
   1569                 pwd = None
   1570 
-> 1571             return ZipExtFile(zef_file, mode, zinfo, pwd, True)
   1572         except:
   1573             zef_file.close()

~\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in __init__(self, fileobj, mode, zipinfo, pwd, close_fileobj)
    817         self._left = zipinfo.file_size
    818 
--> 819         self._decompressor = _get_decompressor(self._compress_type)
    820 
    821         self._eof = False

~\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in _get_decompressor(compress_type)
    718 
    719 def _get_decompressor(compress_type):
--> 720     _check_compression(compress_type)
    721     if compress_type == ZIP_STORED:
    722         return None

~\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in _check_compression(compression)
    698                 "Compression requires the (missing) lzma module")
    699     else:
--> 700         raise NotImplementedError("That compression method is not supported")
    701 
    702 

NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported
```

I have also noticed that the code works for zipfile that are smaller in size, while the error message is only raised for larger zipfiles. I am not sure why this is the case when all the zipfiles are being created using the same method.

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Please add the full traceback, just the error doesn't give enough information.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I have edited the post with the full traceback! @StrangeSorcerer